# how I can limit the call to only one time for method "utilities.DecryptStringFromBase64String"

Tags: c#

I am getting credential data from one of web service call and while decrypt it, the format is "username:::password". I have other class as well and finally I am creating Data class like below,

```
 var lstStudents = new List<Student>
        {
            new Student
            {
                Name = "studen1",
                Credentials = new List<Credential> {new Credential {Key = "N1", Cred = "pNn/B3yUB+x2yiC310efoAjb8EkNhH1oD3NYF0v5SNxUKPtOtpxL21saVJGjmYPi" }, new Credential { Key = "N2", Cred = "" }}
            },
            new Student
            {
                Name = "studen2",
                Credentials = new List<Credential> {new Credential {Key = "N1", Cred = "PT7CpnUcG7DIrJTxN8CcqoHAyTbNNST3DzGLpGQUHF6/jyooYKW1puXb/a+WX2M8" }, new Credential { Key = "N2", Cred = "" }}
            },
        };

        var filterList = lstStudents.SelectMany(x => x.Credentials.Select(y => 
                new Data
                {
                    StudentName = x.Name, 
                    CredentialKey = y.Key,
                    UserName = utilities.DecryptStringFromBase64String(y.Cred, key).Before(":::") , 
                    Password = utilities.DecryptStringFromBase64String(y.Cred, key).After(":::")
                }))
            .Where(d => d.CredentialKey == "N1")
            .ToList();
```

Supporting classes,

```
public class Data
{
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public string CredentialKey { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Credential> Credentials { get; set; }
}

public class Credential
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Cred { get; set; }
}
```

In above code I am calling method `DecryptStringFromBase64String` 2 times, I would like to call it only one time and prepare my data class, how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Use [multiline lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5653703/1997232). Store result of call into local variable and then use that variable twice with `Before` and `After`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be easier if you tweak the query to use the actual LINQ language syntax (rather than the extension methods), as then you can use `let`:

```cs
var filterList = (
    from x in lstStudents
    from y in x.Credentials
    let s = utilities.DecryptStringFromBase64String(y.Cred, key)
    let d = new Data
    {
        StudentName = x.Name,
        CredentialKey = y.Key,
        UserName = s.Before(":::"),
        Password = s.After(":::")
    }
    where d.CredentialKey == "N1"
    select d
).ToList();
```

or to do the `where` sooner, to avoid some calculations / allocations:

```cs
var filterList = (
    from x in lstStudents
    from y in x.Credentials
    where y.Key == "N1"
    let s = utilities.DecryptStringFromBase64String(y.Cred, key)
    let d = new Data
    {
        StudentName = x.Name,
        CredentialKey = y.Key,
        UserName = s.Before(":::"),
        Password = s.After(":::")
    }
    select d
).ToList();
```

Personally I'd also change all the `x`, `y`, `s`, `d` to be more meaningful, but I've left them the same for now, so you can see how it maps.

An alternative would be, as noted by @Sinatr in the comments, to use a lambda with body:

```cs
var filterList = lstStudents.SelectMany(x => x.Credentials.Select(y => {
    var s = utilities.DecryptStringFromBase64String(y.Cred, key);
    return new Data {
        StudentName = x.Name, 
        CredentialKey = y.Key,
        UserName = s.Before(":::") , 
        Password = s.After(":::")
    };
}))
.Where(d => d.CredentialKey == "N1")
.ToList();
```

Comment: @user584018 btw, if you more the `where d.CredentialKey == "N1"` up a few levels, to `where y.Key == "N1"` before the `let s = ...` - you would shave off some unnecessary calculations and allocations

Comment: Could you please post the  query.  Not getting it