# Convert if else statement to simple linq query

Tags: c#, linq

I have been trying to convert a simple if else to a linq statement.

The if else statement goes something like this:

```
if ( MessageStatus = 1 )
   then MessageCount > 0
else if ( MessageStatus = 2 )
   then MessageCount = 0
else
   do nothing
```

This is what I have in my linq so far and it didn't query out the data I wanted

```
var query = _context.Message
                    .Where(c => request.MessageStatus.Equal(2) ? c.MessageCount.Equals(0) :
                                   request.MessageStatus.Equal(1) ? c.MessageCount > 0 :
                                      request.MessageStatus.Equal(0));
```

It should be able to return rows of data but instead it return nothing.

Where does the problems lie at?

Thanks

Comment: Is this query being translated into SQL, such as with Entity Framework? If so, have you inspected the generated query? Is there a need to do such complicated filtering in the query? Could you adjust your schema to make this problem simpler? In addition, we can't exactly answer "why do I get no results" without an [mre], which would include example data.

Comment: @gunr2171 do u mean put those if else statement into Where? I can't seem to do it sorry

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? If we're working with enumerables/collections, are those if blocks supposed to be something that adds to a list when MessageStatus = 1 and MessageCount > 0, etc? Its not clear what the objective is here

Comment: What does `then MessageCount > 0` mean in your code. This `MessageCount > 0` is a Boolean expression, not a statement

Comment: @Aggragoth I'm trying to extract data from list based on the MessageStatus. Like for example, when the MessageStatus = 1, which means that only query out the Message that have the MessageCount of more than 0

Comment: @gunr2171 [Making a lambda multiple statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653703/can-a-c-sharp-lambda-expression-have-more-than-one-statement) cant work for me sorry. Im using EF

Comment: @Flydog57 I'm trying to extract data from list based on the MessageStatus. Like for example, when the MessageStatus = 1, which means that only query out the Message that have the MessageCount of more than 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're asking about is *conditional filtering*. `request.MessageStatus` is a value you know *before* you execute the query, so you can use it to define which `Where` to add to the query.

This works by creating a `IQueryable<...>` for the whole data set (your table), then *adding on* the `Where` that you want based on some condition. It's important to note that you're always doing `query = query.Where(...);`, if you don't re-assign `query` you lose the additional filter.

```
// "request" is defined earlier
IQueryable<Message> query = _context.Message; // might need .AsQueryable() here

if (request.MessageStatus == 1)
{
    query = query.Where(r => r.MessageCount > 0);
}
else if (request.MessageStatus == 2)
{
    query = query.Where(r => r.MessageCount = 0);
}
else
{
    // assuming that this means "include all records",
    // don't perform any additional filtering
    // you don't need this "else"
}

List<Message> results = query.ToList();
```

It's also good to know that this pattern works outside of EF as well with basic `IEnumerable`s and in memory collections.

Comment: Side note, I'm noticing that you're using a lot of `something.Equals(something)`. 99% of the time in C# you use `==` for equality comparison, such as `request.MessageStatus == 2` rather than `request.MessageStatus.Equal(2)`. If you come from a Java background this might be why.